# Find and replace a character from the select text NotePad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I am having a lot of text similar t the following in my code which I am trying to edit with notepad++:

```
except ValueError, err:
except Exception,err:
except RPCFault, err:
```

Not what I am trying to do is to modify the text like the following:

```
except ValueError as err:
except Exception as err:
except RPCFault as err:
```

For making the above changes I tried to use the regex:  `except.*,` in the find box and in replace box:  `except.* as`

But this did not help. Kindly suggest me what I need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Search Mode Regular expression
Replace

```
(except\ [A-Za-z]+),\ *(err:)
```

with

```
$1 as $2
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is only one comma in each line:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^except [^,]+\K, *(?=err:$), *(?=err:$)`
- Replace with: `as`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                   : begining of line
  except [^,]+      : literally "except", followed by a space and 1 or more non comma
  \K                : forget all we have seen until this position
  ,                 : a comma
   *                : 0 or more spaces
  (?=               : look ahead, zero length assertion that makes sure we have after
    err:$           : literally "err:" at end of line
  )                 : end lookahead
```

**Replacement:**

```
 as     : a space, "as", a space
```

**Result for given example:**

```
except ValueError as err:
except Exception as err:
except RPCFault as err:
```